# Нужна ли запятая перед как

Tags: пунктуация

Он со стены глядит как совесть,
Такой внимательнейший взгляд...
Считаю, что оборот с как входит в состав сказуемого. У автора стоит запятая перед как, я бы убрала. Так ли я рассуждаю Помогите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаю, что Вы правы. Это, действительно, составное именное сказуемое (глядит как совесть = является  совестью)

Answer (score 1):

Он со стены глядит как совесть, Такой внимательнейший взгляд.

Запятая не нужна, сравнительный оборот в роли необособленного обстоятельства образа действия. Оборот выделен логическим ударением, перед ним не делается пауза.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая в Вашем предложении была поставлена правильно. Сравнительный оборот "как совесть" выражен именем существительным в именительном падеже, потенциально выступающим в роли господствующего состава. По смыслу близок к  двусоставному предложению "как глядит совесть", поэтому запятая нужна. [Сравнительный оборот](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1585/%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Comment: Как зарницы в небе они запылали, как огненный дождь с неба упали.  А эти сравнительные обороты можно развернуть в  предложение? И что означает термин "господствующий состав"?